# Adding a variable along with multiple selectors in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add variable `i` in `#red` `green` etc. in following?

```
$( "#red'+i', #green'+i', #blue'+i'" ).slider({ 
    orientation: "horizontal", 
    range: "min", 
    max: 255, 
    value: 127, 
    slide: refreshSwatch, 
    change: refreshSwatch 
});
```

I have no clue about this so far, please advise.

Comment: how you are getting the value of `i`?

Comment: Copy pasted code is amazing.

Comment: It's ok now. Thanks!
`$(document).ready(function () {
 var i = 0;

     $('.container').on('click', '.dodaj', function () {
       i++;
   function refreshSwatch() {

    var red = $( "#red"+i ).slider( "value" ),
      green = $( "#green"+i ).slider( "value" ),
      blue = $( "#blue"+i ).slider( "value" ),
      hex = hexFromRGB( red, green, blue );
    $( ".swatch" ).css( "color", "#" + hex );
    $( "#red_val"+i ).text( "#" + hex );
  }
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#red" + i + ", #green" + i + ", #blue" + i).slider({ 
    orientation: "horizontal", 
    range: "min", 
    max: 255, 
    value: 127, 
    slide: refreshSwatch, 
    change: refreshSwatch 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select all the elements that have red, green or blue in the id string you can use

```
$("[id*=red], [id*=green], [id*=blue]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign/create the string before passing to `slider` like this...

```
var selector = '#red' + i + ', #green' + i + ', #blue' + i;
$(selector).slider({ 
    orientation: "horizontal", 
    range: "min", 
    max: 255, 
    value: 127, 
    slide: refreshSwatch, 
    change: refreshSwatch 
});
```

But IMO, you should look for simplifying your selector. This could become hassle when code grows.